whenNotPaused I have right import for using this but it igves error Identifier not found or not unique
line 77     whenNotPaused      gives error I have right import for using this but it igves error Identifier not found or not unique.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol";
import "../interfaces/IShares.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Shares is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("PropertyShare", "SHARE") {
        // Initialize Ownable and Pausable contracts
        Ownable.initialize(msg.sender);
        Pausable.initialize(msg.sender);
    }
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    using Math for uint256;

    // Struct for Share Basket
    struct ShareBasket {
        uint256 basketId;
        uint256[] propertyIds;
        uint256 totalShares;
    }

    // State variables
    mapping(uint256 => ShareBasket) public baskets;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public basketShares; // Basket ID to total shares

    // Struct for Property Shares
    struct PropertyShares {
        uint256 totalShares;
        uint256 availableShares;
        mapping(address => uint256) shareholders;
    }

    // Mappings for property shares and owners
    mapping(uint256 => PropertyShares) public propertyShares;
    mapping(uint256 => address) public propertyOwners;

    // Events
    event SharesIssued(address indexed investor, uint256 indexed propertyId, uint256 sharesIssued);
    event SharesTransferred(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 indexed propertyId, uint256 sharesTransferred);

    // Constructor
    constructor() {
        _pause(); // Optionally initialize the contract in a paused state
        _mint(msg.sender, 0); // Mint initial supply of 0 tokens
    }

    // Function to create a new share basket
    function createBasket(uint256 basketId, uint256[] memory propertyIds, uint256 totalShares) external onlyOwner {
        baskets[basketId] = ShareBasket({
            basketId: basketId,
            propertyIds: propertyIds,
            totalShares: totalShares
        });
        basketShares[basketId] = totalShares;
    }

    // Function to issue shares for a specific basket
    function issueShares(uint256 basketId, address to, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        require(basketShares[basketId] >= amount, "Insufficient shares available");
        _mint(to, amount);
        basketShares[basketId] -= amount;
    }

    // Function to get basket details
    function getBasketDetails(uint256 basketId) external view returns (ShareBasket memory) {
        return baskets[basketId];
    }

    // Function to issue shares for a specific property
    function issueSharesForProperty(uint256 propertyId, address investor, uint256 shares) external onlyOwner whenNotPaused  {
        require(shares > 0, "Shares must be greater than 0");
        require(propertyShares[propertyId].availableShares >= shares, "Not enough shares available");
        
        PropertyShares storage sharesData = propertyShares[propertyId];
        sharesData.totalShares += shares;
        sharesData.availableShares -= shares;
        sharesData.shareholders[investor] += shares;

        emit SharesIssued(investor, propertyId, shares);
    }

    // Function to transfer shares between investors
    function transferShares(uint256 propertyId, address to, uint256 shares) external whenNotPaused {
        require(to != address(0), "Invalid recipient address");
        require(propertyShares[propertyId].shareholders[msg.sender] >= shares, "Not enough shares to transfer");
        
        PropertyShares storage sharesData = propertyShares[propertyId];
        sharesData.shareholders[msg.sender] -= shares;
        sharesData.shareholders[to] += shares;

        emit SharesTransferred(msg.sender, to, propertyId, shares);
    }

    // Function to get the number of shares held by an address
    function getShares(uint256 propertyId, address shareholder) external view returns (uint256) {
        return propertyShares[propertyId].shareholders[shareholder];
    }

    // Function to get the total number of shares issued for a property
    function getTotalShares(uint256 propertyId) external view returns (uint256) {
        return propertyShares[propertyId].totalShares;
    }

    // Function to get the available shares for a property
    function getAvailableShares(uint256 propertyId) external view returns (uint256) {
        return propertyShares[propertyId].availableShares;
    }

    // Function to set the property owner address (useful for verification or integration)
    function setPropertyOwner(uint256 propertyId, address owner) external onlyOwner {
        require(owner != address(0), "Invalid owner address");
        propertyOwners[propertyId] = owner;
    }

    // Function to get the property owner
    function getPropertyOwner(uint256 propertyId) external view returns (address) {
        return propertyOwners[propertyId];
    }

    // Function to pause the contract in emergencies
    function pause() external onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    // Function to unpause the contract
    function unpause() external onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    // Placeholder for external integration (e.g., with external systems or protocols)
    function integrateWithExternalSystem(uint256 /* propertyId */) external pure returns (bool) {
        // Example integration logic
        return true;
    }
}










You didn't inherit the Pausable contract.
As per the documentation:

This module is used through inheritance. It will make available the
modifiers whenNotPaused and whenPaused, which can be applied to
the functions of your contract. Note that they will not be pausable by
simply including this module, only once the modifiers are put in place.


I see multiple errors there.
For the pausable error, you need to inherit the pausable contract:
contract Shares is ERC20, Ownable, Pausable

Why do you have two constructors? There should only be one.
What are you trying to initialize inside the constructor? These are not upgradeable contracts, this is how your constructor should be:
constructor() ERC20("PropertyShare", "SHARE") Ownable(msg.sender) {
        _pause(); // Optionally initialize the contract in a paused state
        _mint(msg.sender, 0); // Mint initial supply of 0 tokens
    }

